# jquery script in mvc layout is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a litle jquery script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AjaxTest", "Home")',
        })
    });
```

When I include it directly in the layout page of my MVC application it works as I expect. When I'm trying to call it from an external file(infoAjax.js) it fails and I get message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). My bundle file:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/infoAjax.js"
                  ));
```

and responsible part of layout page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: @Url.Action won't work in a JS file. That's Razor syntax so it has to be within a view. If you look at your network tab when you run it from the external file you'll probably find it's trying to call a URL literally like http://@Url.Action("AjaxTest", "Home") instead of resolving it to the real URL, which it would do if it was in a cshtml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Url.Action("AjaxTest", "Home") is avaible only View of MVC project. Try to use exact address like

```
 url: 'localhost/Home/AjaxTest',
```

instead of

```
  url: '@Url.Action("AjaxTest", "Home")',
```

Comment: I thought the 404 happened on ~/Scripts/infoAjax.js by the way the question was worded. But this is the reason, definitely

Comment: the only slight issue with hard-coding the URL is that it's vulnerable to changes in the routing config on the MVC side, which is one major reason by the Url.Action helper exists. However this solution will resolve the immediate problem as described in the question.

Comment: @ADyson That is why I think my answer fits a solution that can be deployed without remembering to change the url location each time :P

Comment: @zerohero you already got my upvote when you posted it :-) Both solutions are good as long as you understand the consequences...

Answer (score 3):

As .js files are not parsed by asp.net mvc view engine, you simply cannot use any code in there. I would suggest using unobtrusive approach, something like this

```
<div id="loader" data-request-url="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")"></div>
```

And in javascript, use value of data-request-url

```
$(function(){
   $('#loader').click(function(){
       var url = $(this).data('request-url');
       alert(url);
   });
});
```